# CoreImage: CIColorKernel.init with .metallib causes EXEC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, metal, core-image

I've made a Perlin Noise filter for CoreImage using Metal Shader Language. My first version of it works fine, and allows me to specify 2 colors to use as the `low` and `high`. My next step is to allow it to accept a color map such that it can produce multi-color output. The color map version compiles fine, but when my CIFilter subclass tries to create a CIColorKernel from it using the `init(functionName:fromMetalLibraryData:)` method, I get an `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` with `code=1`. Any idea what about my color map implementation might be causing this?

Here's the simple, 2-color version:

```
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
using namespace metal;

constant int p[512] = {151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180,151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};

float fade(float t) { return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10); }
float grad(int hash, float x, float y, float z) {
    int h = hash & 15;
    float u = h < 8 ? x : y;
    float v = h < 4 ? y : h == 12 || h == 14 ? x : z;
    return ((h & 1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h & 2) == 0 ? v : -v);
}
float lerp(float t, float x, float y) { return x + t * (y - x); }

float noise(float x, float y, float z) {
    int X = (int)floor(x) & 255;
    int Y = (int)floor(y) & 255;
    int Z = (int)floor(z) & 255;

    x -= floor(x);
    y -= floor(y);
    z -= floor(z);

    float u = fade(x);
    float v = fade(y);
    float w = fade(z);

    int A =  p[X    ] + Y;
    int AA = p[A    ] + Z;
    int AB = p[A + 1] + Z;
    int B =  p[X + 1] + Y;
    int BA = p[B    ] + Z;
    int BB = p[B + 1] + Z;

    float result = lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA  ], x  , y  , z   ),  // AND ADD
                                           grad(p[BA  ], x-1, y  , z   )), // BLENDED
                                   lerp(u, grad(p[AB  ], x  , y-1, z   ),  // RESULTS
                                           grad(p[BB  ], x-1, y-1, z   ))),// FROM  8
                           lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x  , y  , z-1 ),  // CORNERS
                                           grad(p[BA+1], x-1, y  , z-1 )), // OF CUBE
                                   lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x  , y-1, z-1 ),
                                           grad(p[BB+1], x-1, y-1, z-1 ))));
    return (result + 1.0) / 2.0;
}


extern "C" float4 PerlinNoise (float4 lowColor, float4 highColor, float offsetX, float offsetY, float offsetZ, float scale, float contrast, coreimage::destination dest)
{
    float val = noise(dest.coord().x * scale + offsetX, dest.coord().y * scale + offsetY, offsetZ);
    return mix(lowColor, highColor, pow(val, contrast));
}
```

And here is the color map version:

```
#include <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>
using namespace metal;

constant uint8_t p[512] = {151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180,151,160,137,91,90,15,131,13,201,95,96,53,194,233,7,225,140,36,103,30,69,142,8,99,37,240,21,10,23,190,6,148,247,120,234,75,0,26,197,62,94,252,219,203,117,35,11,32,57,177,33,88,237,149,56,87,174,20,125,136,171,168,68,175,74,165,71,134,139,48,27,166,77,146,158,231,83,111,229,122,60,211,133,230,220,105,92,41,55,46,245,40,244,102,143,54,65,25,63,161,1,216,80,73,209,76,132,187,208,89,18,169,200,196,135,130,116,188,159,86,164,100,109,198,173,186,3,64,52,217,226,250,124,123,5,202,38,147,118,126,255,82,85,212,207,206,59,227,47,16,58,17,182,189,28,42,223,183,170,213,119,248,152,2,44,154,163,70,221,153,101,155,167,43,172,9,129,22,39,253,19,98,108,110,79,113,224,232,178,185,112,104,218,246,97,228,251,34,242,193,238,210,144,12,191,179,162,241,81,51,145,235,249,14,239,107,49,192,214,31,181,199,106,157,184,84,204,176,115,121,50,45,127,4,150,254,138,236,205,93,222,114,67,29,24,72,243,141,128,195,78,66,215,61,156,180};

float fade(float t) { return t * t * t * (t * (t * 6 - 15) + 10); }
float grad(uint8_t hash, float x, float y, float z) {
    uint8_t h = hash & 15;
    float u = h < 8 ? x : y;
    float v = h < 4 ? y : h == 12 || h == 14 ? x : z;
    return ((h & 1) == 0 ? u : -u) + ((h & 2) == 0 ? v : -v);
}
float lerp(float t, float x, float y) { return x + t * (y - x); }

float noise(float x, float y, float z) {
    uint8_t X = (uint8_t)floor(x) & 255;
    uint8_t Y = (uint8_t)floor(y) & 255;
    uint8_t Z = (uint8_t)floor(z) & 255;

    x -= floor(x);
    y -= floor(y);
    z -= floor(z);

    float u = fade(x);
    float v = fade(y);
    float w = fade(z);

    uint8_t A =  p[X    ] + Y;
    uint8_t AA = p[A    ] + Z;
    uint8_t AB = p[A + 1] + Z;
    uint8_t B =  p[X + 1] + Y;
    uint8_t BA = p[B    ] + Z;
    uint8_t BB = p[B + 1] + Z;

    float result = lerp(w, lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA  ], x  , y  , z   ),  // AND ADD
                                           grad(p[BA  ], x-1, y  , z   )), // BLENDED
                                   lerp(u, grad(p[AB  ], x  , y-1, z   ),  // RESULTS
                                           grad(p[BB  ], x-1, y-1, z   ))),// FROM  8
                           lerp(v, lerp(u, grad(p[AA+1], x  , y  , z-1 ),  // CORNERS
                                           grad(p[BA+1], x-1, y  , z-1 )), // OF CUBE
                                   lerp(u, grad(p[AB+1], x  , y-1, z-1 ),
                                           grad(p[BB+1], x-1, y-1, z-1 ))));
    return (result + 1.0) / 2.0;
}

float4 colormapLookup(float value, size_t count, float indices[], float4 colormap[]) {
    // If the value is at the outside boundary, just return the boundary color.
    if (value < indices[0]) {
        return colormap[0];
    } else if (value >= indices[count - 1]) {
        return colormap[count - 1];
    }

    // Find which 2 indices the value falls between.
    size_t index = 0;
    while (value < indices[index] && index < count - 1) {
        index++;
    }
    float startIndex = indices[index];
    float endIndex = indices[index+1];

    // Calculate the normalized offset between those indies.
    float offset = (value - startIndex) / (endIndex - startIndex);

    // Return the blended color for that offest.
    return mix(colormap[index], colormap[index+1], offset);
}


extern "C" float4 PerlinNoise (size_t count, float indices[], float4 colormap[], float offsetX, float offsetY, float offsetZ, float scale, float contrast, coreimage::destination dest)
{
    float val = noise(dest.coord().x * scale + offsetX, dest.coord().y * scale + offsetY, offsetZ);
    return colormapLookup(pow(val, contrast), count, indices, colormap);
}
```

Here's the method where I attempt to instantiate the CIColorKernel. The `EXEC_BAD_ACCESS` happens on the line where the CIColorKernel init function is called:

```
    static var kernel: CIColorKernel? = {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PerlinNoiseGenerator", withExtension: "ci.metallib") else { return nil }

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            return try CIColorKernel(functionName: "PerlinNoise", fromMetalLibraryData: data)
        } catch {
            print("[ERROR] Failed to create CIColorKernel: \(error)")
        }
        return nil
    }()
```

*Edit: Added the Swift code where the CIColorKernel is being instantiated.*

Comment: I'm afraid arrays of arbitrary size (or pointers) are not supported as parameters of kernel functions in Metal (or GPU code in general). If you don't know the size beforehand, you probably need to put the values into a `CIImage` and pass it as a `sampler` parameter to the kernel.

Comment: D'oh! Thank you! It'd be lovely if the documentation mentioned that anywhere…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Frank's comment, I reverted my Perlin Noise filter to its original, functional state and instead applied the color map as a following step using this improved version of the `CIColorMap` filter which can generate its own gradient image based on a [CGFloat: CIColor] dictionary.

```
import CoreImage

class ImprovedColorMap: CIFilter {

    enum ColorMapError: Error {
        case unableToCreateCGContext
        case unableToCreateCGGradient
    }

    private var _colorMap: [CGFloat: CIColor] = [
        0.0: .black,
        1.0: .white,
    ]

    private var gradientImage: CIImage = CIImage()

    private var mapFilter: CIFilter? = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMap")

    var inputImage: CIImage?

    var inputColorMap: [CGFloat: CIColor] {
        get { _colorMap }
        set {
            guard newValue.keys.count >= 2 else {
                print("ERROR: Color map must have at least 2 entries. Change will be ignored.")
                return
            }
            _colorMap = newValue
            generateGradient()
        }
    }

    override var outputImage: CIImage? {
        guard let filter = mapFilter else {
            return nil
        }
        filter.setValue(gradientImage, forKey: kCIInputGradientImageKey)
        filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        return filter.outputImage
    }

    init(colorMap: [CGFloat: CIColor]? = nil) {
        if let colorMap = colorMap {
            _colorMap = colorMap
        }
        super.init()
        generateGradient()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    private func generateGradient() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
            guard let context = CGContext(data: nil, width: 512, height: 16, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 512 * 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue) else {
                print("ERROR: Could not create CGContext.")
                return
            }
            var locations: [CGFloat] = []
            var components: [CGFloat] = []
            for (location, color) in self._colorMap {
                locations.append(location)
                components.append(contentsOf: color.floatComponents)
            }
            guard let gradient = CGGradient(colorSpace: colorSpace, colorComponents: components, locations: locations, count: locations.count) else {
                print("ERROR: Could not create CGGradient.")
                return
            }
            context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: .zero, end: CGPoint(x: 512.0, y: 0.0), options: [])
            guard let image = context.makeImage() else {
                print("ERROR: Failed to create image from context.")
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.gradientImage = CIImage(cgImage: image)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That works well, except now I realize that traditional Perlin Noise is too smooth for realistic-looking terrain, so I'm moving on to creating a Simplex Noise metal kernel next.